# Creating an Angular project that uses a PHP login system running on Xampp

Tags: php, mysql, angular, web-applications, xampp

I have created a login system running on XAMPP for a web app using php, html, materialise for css, and a tiny bit of javascript. The system consists of login, signup, and index pages. In addition, a database is implemented to store user data and app data in the future. If all form validation is verified, a user's sign up details are stored in the database, after which they can log in normally. If a user successfully logs in, a session is started using the start_session() and SESSION global variable of php. The index page indicates whether a session is currently in progress.

Once a session is in progress, I want to display the application contents (yet to be developed) on the index page where a user can practice their functionalities and log out when they want. I want to implement this logic using angular but I'm confused as to how I'm going to get angular to work with the php login system and the database that are running on xampp. I'm a beginner to angular (and development in general) but from what I understand it comes with it's own "server" so the application contents can be hosted locally. Does anyone have any idea how I can get the angular app working with my  implementated database and php login system? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am learning angular now a day but I think I can answer your question. By default angular serve your application on localhost:4200. This application would contain your UI and interaction logic. After the app gets loaded in the browser, your application would call PHP script as you would have normally called with HTML because now everything is on browser so you need not to bother about angular server.
However in angular, you should utilize angular services to make server request.

Your web architecture would look like this (think of apache in place of nginx)
[image]